# Loading a new viewController on the same tab bar item not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So I am having a problem loading a new view controller on the same tab bar item. I have a tab bar controller as my root controller and 4 tabs on the tab bar. One of which is the account tab, when the user is logged in he would need to see an overview of his account details but when there is no user there needs to be a sign-in / login page on that tab bar item. For the moment I have a custom tab bar class for my tabbarcontroller with a function that I thought was the solution but nothing happens. I have put a breakpoint in the view controller that needs to loaded (the user detail page) and it comes in the ViewDidLoad so it loads but it doesn't appear on the screen.

Hope I can finally solve this problem!

Kind regards
B.

this is my custom tab bar controller class:

```
import UIKit

class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self

    }


    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController,
                          shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool{
        let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        window = UIWindow(frame: frame)
        let index = tabBarController.viewControllers?.firstIndex(of: viewController)
        if index == 3{ // Index of Account tab
            let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let loginVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
            window?.rootViewController = loginVC
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        return true// you decide
    }
}
```

Comment: try to set rootViewController of existing widow ? tried that ?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am pretty new to the swift language so how would I do such thing if I may ask? Do I take the account view controller and take the window of that or do something else? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code that presents full screen loginVc

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController,
                          shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool{
        let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        window = UIWindow(frame: frame)
        let index = tabBarController.viewControllers?.firstIndex(of: viewController)
        if index == 1{ // Index of Account tab
            let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let loginVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
            loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(loginVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
        return true// you decide
    }
```

If you also want to have bottom bar ... your that viewController should be Navigation Controller and you can push your desired ViewController then like

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController,
                          shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool{
        let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        window = UIWindow(frame: frame)
        let index = tabBarController.viewControllers?.firstIndex(of: viewController)
        if index == 1{ // Index of Account tab
            let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let loginVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
           // loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

            if let navigation = viewController as? UINavigationController {

                navigation.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: false)
            }
        }
        return true// you decide
    }
```

It will show back button and navigationBar on top 
if you dont want NavigationBar then in your `MessagesViewController` did load function call

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

And if you just want to hide back button then call

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false);
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Comment: you want to have tabBar on bottom as well ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! Yes in the ideal case it would need a tab bar on the bottom.

Comment: then your 3rd view controller should be NavigationController ... and you can push your desire controller over it ...

Comment: let me kow how i can help you more

Comment: do you get the tabBar and controller ?

Comment: or i can share a test project with you ... that i built for this aswer

Comment: we.tl/t-bRFv16j8U6 ... here is the link of test project for your help

Answer (score 0):

Changing your rootViewController is bad practice in Swift.

The correct way to handle tasks like this is to override your accountViewController's viewWillAppear function to determine if the user isn't logged in and present your loginViewController. Try something like:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // authManager would be a custom class that manages authorization with a property for loggedIn
    if authManager.loggedIn == false {
        guard let loginVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login") as? LoginViewController else { return }
        self.present(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply. I tried such a thing last week but the problem is that it gives me a pop up of the detail screen and not a full screen of the account detail page so also without a tab bar. Is there a way that I can let this function work with the account detail page as a full screen with the tab bar controller included? Thank you in advance

Comment: @BrechtVerhelst, yeah if you want your loginViewController inside your tabBarController, it will add a tab as well. You could alternatively make your account tab a UINavigationController and use navController.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: false)